# Suggest some word

Tags: single-word-requests

Can someone suggest a list of words used for a single  thing (robot, machine, website, human, etc.) that can do multiple operations?

I am searching for a word that I can use for something that do many thing alone.

I want it for website name.

Comment: Probably  'multitasking unit' or 'multitasker'.

Comment: Bot and appliance .

Comment: ....all-rounder

Comment: **A Polymath!**

Answer (score 1):

Wait: one of these things is not like the others: "*robot*, *machine*, ***website***, *human*".

In every case except "website", these systems are ***autonomous***; that is, they operate independent of outside influence. They can, in effect, decide what's needed to get the job done, and then do it.

And, getting to the heart of your question, typically autonomous systems are provided with a variety of tools to meet a correspondingly broad variety of situations (i.e. autonomous systems can both plan and implement).

But a website doesn't have this characteristic: it doesn't operate on its own. It may be *multi-functional*, like a Swiss Army knife, as @Gary's Student suggests, but also like a Swiss Army knife, a website is designed as a *tool*, to be used by *someone else* to meet *his own ends*. A website, qua a website, has no ends of its own.

---

**EDIT**:

Ah, I just got it: taking, from your example, *human* to mean human *servant*, and the total collection of your examples to mean "something which [you] can [instruct to] perform a task for you, so you don't have to worry about it (or any of the fiddly details)", then you're not looking for *autonomous*, you're looking for ***automatic***.

Comment: what it would br in case of website

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. A *tool* that can be used to perform many functions is a *multi-function tool*, like a Swiss Army Knife.

Answer (score -1):

**Versatile**

[Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/versatile):

> having many uses or applications  A pocketknife is a versatile tool.